# Guzzle: avoid automatic retrying

Tags: guzzle

Can we tell GuzzleHttp to *not* retry if a call do not ends with a 200-ok?

Actually I'm getting in some situations a huge list of retry, all ending as "Client Error, bad request".

I need to avoid retry, at least in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guzzle doesn't do any retries by default. It bundles with [a retry middleware](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.5.0/src/RetryMiddleware.php), but it has to be configured manually for your client, and fully decide about the retry strategy.

You can take a look at [an example strategy](https://github.com/productsupcom/guzzle-examples/blob/master/src/Guzzle/RetryHandler.php) that retries 5 times max when there is a connection issue or the server responded with 5xx.